# geoDjango point geom field

Tags: geodjango

I can't figure out why the geom field is so long, I can't make heads or tails of the number either.

[image]

Comment: Is that the binary representation of the geometry?

Comment: I think so, I'm not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a geometry column is shown as WKB(Well Known Binary), you probably want to show it as WKT(Well Known Text)

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM table
```

For example:

```
gis=# select way from planet_osm_point limit 1;
                    way
----------------------------------------------------
010100002031BF0D005C8FC24D5C856BC15C8FC27573C85741
(1 row)

gis=# select ST_AsText(way) from planet_osm_point limit 1;
       st_astext
--------------------------------
POINT(-14428898.43 6234573.84)
(1 row)
```